# WebView causing Uncaught TypeError when loading my html Data

Tags: android, html, webview, vast

Im using WebView to Vpaid html5player into an app.Webview occur in javascript error..

```
08-01 10:20:06.967: I/chromium(24646): [INFO:CONSOLE(60)] "Uncaught TypeError: this[a] is not a function", source: http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js (60)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gowsample;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private WebView mWebview ;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" }) 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebview  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    WebSettings settings = mWebview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    String summary = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><!-- Video.js 4 -->\n<link href=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n<script src=\"http://mysite/VPAID1/video.js\"></script>\n<!-- Common -->\n<link href=\"http://mysite/bin/videojs.vast.vpaid.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n<!-- Video.js 5 -->\n<script src=\"http://mysite/bin/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.min.js\"></script>\n<script src=\"http://mysite/bin/es5-shim.js\"></script>\n<script src=\"http://mysite/VPAID/bin/ie8fix.js\"></script>\n<video id=\"example_video_1\" class=\"video-js vjs-default-skin\"\n    controls preload=\"auto\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"\n    poster=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png\"\n    data-setup='{\n      \"plugins\": {\n      \"vastClient\": {\n        \"adTagUrl\": \"http://mysite/sincity.xml\",\n        \"adCancelTimeout\": 5000,\n        \"adsEnabled\": true\n        }\n      }\n    }'>\n  <source src=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4\" type='video/mp4'/>\n\n \n</video>\n</html>";

 String html =summary;

 mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
@Override
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
    Log.d("Moorthy", consoleMessage.message() + " -- From line "
            + consoleMessage.lineNumber() + " of "
            + consoleMessage.sourceId());
    return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
   }
   });

   mWebview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);

   //mWebview.loadUrl("http://dhmoorthy94.000webhostapp.com/vpaid/VPAID1/secretmedia.php");    

      }

   }
```

Any idea what could be causing these errors?

Note:`mWebview.loadUrl` its perfectly working..but load data pass the same value javascript error occur...

Comment: webView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");

Comment: try this @Moorthy

Comment: Thank u For Reply,But webView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8"); this also not working @nihal_softy

Comment: I tested your code and found that there is an Video page occuring on WebView.. So exactly what you want ?

Comment: are you usre you are giving permission for internet in manifest ?

Answer (score -2):

I copied your code and tested in my Machine.. Things are fine. When I was looking your HTML data, There is an URL which need internet to load on WebView. So what I did, I gave permissions only and your code is working fine so

1. Open your Manifest file.
2. Add **internet** permission.

Comment: internet permission also given but not working.. pls Chk this link http://dhmoorthy94.000webhostapp.com/vpaid/VPAID1/secretmedia.php how it works in browser above link simillary it's wants to be work in webview loaddata using..can u help me

Comment: yes.. Same I am getting and after tapping on button, Video start playing...

Comment: Video will be play but two video playing ah?